# Getting error after installing date-fns dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

After installing date-fns using > "npm install date-fns --save" getting this error

*Attempted import error: 'date-fns' does not contain a default export (imported as 'dateFns').*

I look for some solutions, that I need to change name of my import but still not working. Anyone can help?

And here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dateFns from "date-fns";
import "./Calendar.scss";

const Calendar = () => {
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const header = () => {
    const dateFormat = "MMMM YYYY";
    return (
      <div className="header row flex-middle">
        <div className="column col-start">
          <div className="icon" onClick={prevMonth}>
            chevron_left
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column col-center">
          <span>{dateFns.format(currentDate, dateFormat)}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="column col-end">
          <div className="icon" onClick={nextMonth}>
            chevron_right
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  const days = () => {
    const dateFormat = "ddd";
    const days = [];
    let startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(currentDate);
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      days.push(
        <div className="column col-center" key={i}>
          {dateFns.format(dateFns.addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div className="days row">{days}</div>;
  };
  const cells = () => {
    const monthStart = dateFns.startOfMonth(currentDate);
    const monthEnd = dateFns.endOfMonth(monthStart);
    const startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(monthStart);
    const endDate = dateFns.endOfWeek(monthEnd);
    const dateFormat = "D";
    const rows = [];
    let days = [];
    let day = startDate;
    let formattedDate = "";
    while (day <= endDate) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        formattedDate = dateFns.format(day, dateFormat);
        const cloneDay = day;
        days.push(
          <div
            className={`column cell ${
              !dateFns.isSameMonth(day, monthStart)
                ? "disabled"
                : dateFns.isSameDay(day, selectedDate)
                ? "selected"
                : ""
            }`}
            key={day}
            onClick={() => onDateClick(dateFns.parse(cloneDay))}
          >
            <span className="number">{formattedDate}</span>
            <span className="bg">{formattedDate}</span>
          </div>
        );
        day = dateFns.addDays(day, 1);
      }
      rows.push(
        <div className="row" key={day}>
          {" "}
          {days}{" "}
        </div>
      );
      days = [];
    }
    return <div className="body">{rows}</div>;
  };
  const nextMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDate(dateFns.addMonths(currentDate, 1));
  };
  const prevMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDate(dateFns.subMonths(currentDate, 1));
  };
  const onDateClick = (day) => {
    setSelectedDate(day);
  };
  return (
    <div className="calendar">
      <div>{header()}</div>
      <div>{days()}</div>
      <div>{cells()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Calendar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import is the reason. The library does not export a single "something".

So, you can't import it the way you do. This is how you should use it:

```
// just an example
import { format, startOfWeek, addDays, subDays } from 'date-fns'

// usage example
<div className="column col-center" key={i}>
    {format(addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}
</div>
```

In a nutshell, just import what you need directly :)

Or, you can try it this way (import everything as an object):

```
import * as dateFns from "date-fns";
```

Should also work and you don't need any other changes in the code.

Finally, a good explanation of JS import/export [here](https://javascript.info/import-export). Might be worth to check .)

Comment: Thank's it works but i still get this error
"RangeError: Use `d` instead of `D` (in `D`) for formatting days of the month to the input `Sun Apr 25 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

Comment: @aleks Okay, check [this table](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.3/docs/format) with accepted format patterns. I'd say it is this line in the code `const dateFormat = "D";` where you need to replace `D` (means Day of Year e.g. 1, 100, 364) with `d` (day of month e.g. 1-31 for Jan)